# What rounded bold cursive font looks like the "Dunked" logo?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

I have been seeing a major trend in these types of fonts, the bold cursive ones. I have been going through many and so far I have found Pacifico an Honey Script. I have tried using font identification websites but they don't seem to be able to find the letters in cursive fonts.

An example is the Dunked logo. Of the top of my head I can't think of any more examples. I know the dunked logo isn't Pacifico or Honey Script. I have a feeling people are using the same few fonts as each other.

**Can anyone tell me what font this is and similar ones fitting the rounded bold cursive style?**

[image: dunked logo]

Comment: It think maybe you will have better luck if you search for "handwriting" rather than cursive. Just a thought.

Comment: I first added font-identification to the title because I think you are first looking for an existing font, right? I'm wondering if you should open a second question for the recommendation (my thought: the existing answer is recommendation, not identification. If someone identifies it, which one would you mark as accepted?)

Comment: The ["Dunked" logo](http://dribbble.com/shots/897428-Dunked) was done by the brilliant [Sergey Shapiro](http://www.sergeyshapiro.com/) following a [concept](http://dribbble.com/shots/897428-Dunked?list=show#comment-2134682) by the equally brilliant [Orman Clark](http://www.ormanclark.com/), the founder of Dunked. As Sergey Shapiro states in [this comment on Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/shots/897428-Dunked?page=2#comment-3409028), "this is a hand drawn logo" ("I don't use fonts").

Comment: I don't want to sound like a spam ad - AND this is more of a longterm solution rather than an immediate answer - but what I've found useful (as I'm always looking for pretty cursive fonts) is to sign up for design cuts - they have deals pretty often for bundles of fonts (including gorgeous cursive ones).  You can build up your library over time :)

Answer (score 3):

As was said the logo was lettered, but probably inspired by real font (the author says he does not use font, nevertheless you can see some similarities) -

[Confetti Font](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tipo-pepel/confetti-tp/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for free fonts.

You can try these:

[Vampiro 1](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Vampiro+One):

[image]

[Lobster](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lobster):

[image]

Or browse around [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) for free script, calligraphic, and handwritten type.

If you don't care whether or not it's free, try [Wavee Weekend Thin](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/wavee-weekend/thin/).

http://cdn.myfonts.net/a_92/u/63/6b8bf44324f4b5954cdd55019e95d3.gif

Comment: Neither of these are rounded, though.

Comment: That's true. I added an additional answer that is rounded. The answer before mine does state that it is a hand drawn logo, but I take it you're looking for something similar. Hopefully my improved answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

"*Milkshake*" is close.  Could be a modified version for the logo: http://fairgoods.com/products/milkshake

[image]